# Connecting a Master/Detail Flow app to a server using Executor (New Thread)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, master-detail, executor

I am attempting to use a Master/Detail flow template in android studio to make an app that reads articles from an rss feed link and displays them as a list on the left hand side and displays the main content on the right side. I need to connect to the server using Executor to make a new thread and replace the placeholder content in the Master/Detail flow template with the information from the feed. I'm mostly confused as to how to actually connect to the server properly with Executor and how to implement it on the class where everything gets put into a list. Please let me know what I should update in my classes and methods.

This is the feed I am using: http://www.goal.com/en/feeds/news?fmt=rss

This is the class where the items will be put into a list on the left hand side:

```
/**
 * This class is to set up the content that will fill the recycler view. As of now it is   filled with Dummy content. Real
 * content will be implemented once server is connected
 */
public class SoccerAPI {



/**
 * Array of dummy content to be displayed in the recyclerview
 */
public static final List<articles> ITEMS = new ArrayList<articles>();

/**
 * Using Hashmap to search the array by id
 */
public static final Map<String, articles> ITEM_MAP = new HashMap<String, articles>();

private static final int COUNT = 25;

static {
    // Adds dummy content to the array
    for (int i = 1; i <= COUNT; i++) {
        addItem(createArticleItem(i));
    }
}

/**
 * adds items to both the array and Hashmap
 * @param item
 */
private static void addItem(articles item) {
    ITEMS.add(item);
    ITEM_MAP.put(item.id, item);
}

/**
 * Creates the item "articles" which is the information from the array
 * @param position
 * @return
 */
private static articles createArticleItem(int position) {
    return new articles(String.valueOf(position), "Item " + position, makeDetails(position));
}

/**
 * Takes the details in the array and displays it in the recycler view
 * @param position
 * @return
 */

private static String makeDetails(int position) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Details about Item: ").append(position);
    for (int i = 0; i < position; i++) {
        builder.append("\nMore details information here.");
    }
    return builder.toString();
}

/**
 * A getters and setters for the dummy content.
 */
public static class articles {
    public final String id;
    public final String content;
    public final String details;

    public articles(String id, String content, String details) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
        this.details = details;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a string version of the dummy content
     * @return
     */

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

}

This is the main host activity:

```
public class SoccerItemDetailHostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * declaring the float variable rateValue to be used in the sharedPreferences for the ratingBar
 */
   private float rateValue;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    AlertDialog.Builder mBuild = new AlertDialog.Builder(SoccerItemDetailHostActivity.this);
    mBuild.setTitle("Please rate the app");
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    Float ratinginsharedpreference = preferences.getFloat("Rating", 0);


    View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.soccerratingbar, null);
    mBuild.setView(mView);
    AlertDialog dialog = mBuild.create();
    final RatingBar ratebar = (RatingBar) mView.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    if (ratinginsharedpreference != 0) {
        ratebar.setRating(ratinginsharedpreference);
    }

    ratebar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            rateValue = rating;
            Toast.makeText(SoccerItemDetailHostActivity.this, "" + rating, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

    Button btnSubmit = (Button) mView.findViewById(R.id.btnSubRating);
    btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            editor.putFloat("Rating", rateValue);
            editor.apply();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank you for rating the app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();



}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActivitySocceritemDetailBinding binding = ActivitySocceritemDetailBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    /**
     * Setting up the buttons to be displayed on screen. Finding the button value in the XML by the id
     */

    Button save = findViewById(R.id.save);
    ImageButton help = findViewById(R.id.help);

    /**
     * Setting up onClickListeners for each of the buttons. Right now only the messages are implemented
     * until the app is connected to the server
     */

    save.setOnClickListener(clk -> {

                Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(binding.getRoot(), "You saved the articles to your favourites", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                snackbar.show();
            }
    );


    help.setOnClickListener(clk -> {
        AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SoccerItemDetailHostActivity.this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Help");
        alertDialog.setMessage("To use this app please click on any of the articles listed on the left" +
                " hand side to view the article in the main viewer. If you would like to save the article" +
                " to your favourites, please hit the 'save' button if you would like to remove the article" +
                " from your favourites please hit the 'delete' button. If you would like to load the article" +
                " in a browser please hit the 'load' button. If you are enjoying the app please rate us" +
                " by clicking on the little star icon under the help icon.");
        alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        alertDialog.show();

    });


    ImageButton favouritesList = findViewById(R.id.goToFavouritesButton);
    favouritesList.setOnClickListener(clk -> {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SoccerFavouritesList.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    });


    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.soccerDrawerLayout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.nav_open, R.string.nav_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.soccerSideMenu);
    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener((item) -> {
        onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return false;
    });

}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menuactions, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.ocTranspoApp:
                Intent ocTranspoApp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OCTranspoActivity.class);
                startActivity(ocTranspoApp);
                onStop();
                break;
            case R.id.carApp:
                Intent carApp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CarActivity.class);
                startActivity(carApp);
                onStop();
                break;
            case R.id.movieApp:
                Intent movieApp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MovieActivity.class);
                startActivity(movieApp);
                onStop();
                break;
            case R.id.soccerApp:
                Intent soccerApp = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SoccerItemDetailHostActivity.class);
                startActivity(soccerApp);
                onStop();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    

}
```

This is the ItemList Fragment on the left side of the screen:

```
/**
 * This fragment combines with the NavController. It shows the list of articles on the left hand side
 */
public class SoccerItemListFragment extends Fragment {


private FragmentSocceritemListBinding binding;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    binding = FragmentSocceritemListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    return binding.getRoot();

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);



    RecyclerView recyclerView = binding.socceritemList;

    /**
     * Finding the layout for this fragment container
     */
    View itemDetailFragmentContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.socceritem_detail_nav_container);

    /* Click Listener to trigger navigation based on if you have
     * a single pane layout or two pane layout
     */
    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = itemView -> {
        SoccerAPI.articles item =
                (SoccerAPI.articles) itemView.getTag();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(SoccerItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, item.id);
        if (itemDetailFragmentContainer != null) {
            Navigation.findNavController(itemDetailFragmentContainer)
                    .navigate(R.id.fragment_socceritem_detail, arguments);
        } else {
            Navigation.findNavController(itemView).navigate(R.id.show_socceritem_detail, arguments);
        }


    };

    /*
     * This lets you see the information from each  article on the bigger part of the screen
     */
    View.OnContextClickListener onContextClickListener = itemView -> {
        SoccerAPI.articles item =
                (SoccerAPI.articles) itemView.getTag();
        Toast.makeText(
                itemView.getContext(),
                "Context click of item " + item.id,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG
        ).show();
        return true;
    };

    setupRecyclerView(recyclerView, onClickListener, onContextClickListener);
}

/**
 * Sets up the recycler view where the articles will be populated. The dummy content is there for now
 * @param recyclerView
 * @param onClickListener
 * @param onContextClickListener
 */

private void setupRecyclerView(
        RecyclerView recyclerView,
        View.OnClickListener onClickListener,
        View.OnContextClickListener onContextClickListener
) {

    recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(
            SoccerAPI.ITEMS,
            onClickListener,
            onContextClickListener
    ));
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
}

/**
 * Setting up the adapter for the recyclerview
 */
public static class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<SoccerAPI.articles> mValues;
    private final View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener;
    private final View.OnContextClickListener mOnContextClickListener;

    SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<SoccerAPI.articles> items,
                                  View.OnClickListener onClickListener,
                                  View.OnContextClickListener onContextClickListener) {
        mValues = items;
        mOnClickListener = onClickListener;
        mOnContextClickListener = onContextClickListener;
    }

    /**
     * Setting up the viewHolder
     * @param parent
     * @param viewType
     * @return
     */

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        SocceritemListContentBinding binding =
                SocceritemListContentBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(binding);

    }

    /**
     * Setting up the onBindViewHolder
     * @param holder
     * @param position
     */

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).id);
        holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).content);

        holder.itemView.setTag(mValues.get(position));
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            holder.itemView.setOnContextClickListener(mOnContextClickListener);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Getting the item count from the array so it knows how many to show on screen
     * @return
     */

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        final TextView mIdView;
        final TextView mContentView;

        ViewHolder(SocceritemListContentBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            mIdView = binding.idText;
            mContentView = binding.content;
        }

    }
}
}
```

And this is the detail fragment on the right hand side:

```
 /**
 * This fragment displays the content from the array in SoccerAPI and displays the information in the bigger part of the
* screen (when in Tablet/Landscape mode).
 */
public class SoccerItemDetailFragment extends Fragment {

/**
 * The fragment argument representing the item ID that this fragment
 * represents.
 */
public static final String ARG_ITEM_ID = "item_id";

/**
 * Setting the content from the articles method in the SoccerAPI class to a variable
 */
private SoccerAPI.articles mItem;
private FragmentSocceritemDetailBinding binding;

/**
 * empty constructor
 */
public SoccerItemDetailFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /**
     * Load the data from the dummy content
     */

    if (getArguments().containsKey(ARG_ITEM_ID)) {

        mItem = SoccerAPI.ITEM_MAP.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    binding = FragmentSocceritemDetailBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View rootView = binding.getRoot();



    /**
     * Show the dummy content as text in a TextView & in the toolbar if available.
     */

    if (mItem != null) {
        TextView textView = binding.socceritemDetail;
        textView.setText(mItem.details);

    }

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executor will help you run tasks in the background or off the main thread, to actually fetch the rss data, you'll have to make use of libraries like [retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)  or [volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley). There are several tutorials available on how to get this done, like this one: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html